# How can I take multiple line matches and assign them to a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm taking output from a `net::ssh` session to an ASA and trying to build a hash per vpn user, then add each hash to an array.

Here is the output when one user is connected. If there is more than one user, you have more lines like this per user:

```
Username:arozar
Index:654
AssignedIP:10.254.254.7
PublicIP:4.2.2.2
Protocol:AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel
License:AnyConnectEssentials
Encryption:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256
Hashing:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1
BytesTx:6104355
BytesRx:1191505
GroupPolicy:vpn
TunnelGroup:anyconnect
LoginTime:08:51:55ESTMonNov32014
Duration:1h:08m:48s
Inactivity:0h:00m:00s
NACResult:Unknown

VLANMapping:N/A
VLAN:none
```

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
  @ac_array = Array.new
  session_output = cmd_session.cmd('show vpn-sessiondb anyconnect')
  cmd_session.close
  session_output.each_line do |line|
    username = line.match(/(?<=Username:)(\w+\S+)/)
    assigned_ip = line.match(/(?<=AssignedIP:)(\w+\S+)/)
    public_ip = line.match(/(?<=PublicIP:)(\w+\S+)/)
    license = line.match(/(?<=License:)(\w+\S+)/)
    bytestx = line.match(/(?<=BytesTx:)(\w+\S+)/)
    bytesrx = line.match(/(?<=BytesRx:)(\w+\S+)/)
    group_policy = line.match(/(?<=GroupPolicy:)(\w+\S+)/)
    tunnel_group = line.match(/(?<=TunnelGroup:)(\w+\S+)/)
```

To put these matches into a hash I've had to do this:

```
    unless username.nil?
      anyconnect_hash = {username:username[0]}
      @ac_array.push(anyconnect_hash)
    end
    unless assigned_ip.nil?
       assigned_ip_hash = {assigned_ip:assigned_ip[0]}
      @ac_array.push(assigned_ip_hash)
    end
    unless public_ip.nil?
      public_ip_hash = {public_ip:public_ip[0]}
      @ac_array.push(public_ip_hash)
    end

    AND SO ONE DOWN THE LINE for all the matches.....
```

But I don't think this is the best way, nor is it really working right in my view. I like to use a one line `unless` statement and assign all matches to the hash from there.

Here is sort of what I'm thinking would be better:

```
    unless username.nil? and assigned_ip.nil? and public_ip.nil?
      anyconnect_hash = {username:username[0], assigned_ip:assigned_ip[0], public_ip:public_ip[0]}
      @ac_array.push(anyconnect_hash)
    end
```

Unfortunately with this setup I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: `unless username.nil? and assigned_ip.nil? and public_ip.nil?` allows for any of those to object to be nil but not all. You probably want to use an and instead of and

Comment: could you not use named match groups? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd start with:

```
text = 'Username:arozar
Index:654
AssignedIP:10.254.254.7
PublicIP:4.2.2.2
Protocol:AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel
License:AnyConnectEssentials
Encryption:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256
Hashing:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1
BytesTx:6104355
BytesRx:1191505
GroupPolicy:vpn
TunnelGroup:anyconnect
LoginTime:08:51:55ESTMonNov32014
Duration:1h:08m:48s
Inactivity:0h:00m:00s
NACResult:Unknown

VLANMapping:N/A
VLAN:none
'

text.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).map{ |l| l.split(':', 2) }.to_h
# => {"Username"=>"arozar",
#     "Index"=>"654",
#     "AssignedIP"=>"10.254.254.7",
#     "PublicIP"=>"4.2.2.2",
#     "Protocol"=>"AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel",
#     "License"=>"AnyConnectEssentials",
#     "Encryption"=>
#      "AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256",
#     "Hashing"=>
#      "AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1",
#     "BytesTx"=>"6104355",
#     "BytesRx"=>"1191505",
#     "GroupPolicy"=>"vpn",
#     "TunnelGroup"=>"anyconnect",
#     "LoginTime"=>"08:51:55ESTMonNov32014",
#     "Duration"=>"1h:08m:48s",
#     "Inactivity"=>"0h:00m:00s",
#     "NACResult"=>"Unknown",
#     "VLANMapping"=>"N/A",
#     "VLAN"=>"none"}
```

If your Ruby version doesn't support `to_h`, wrap the command in [`Hash[...]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Append that to an array to aggregate all the created hashes using something like:

```
user_hashes = []
users.each do |user|
  user_hashes << user.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).map{ |l| l.split(':', 2) }.to_h
end
```

Without an example of the log showing two users, instead of one, I can't break down how to split the output by user, but it should be very easy. Cobbling up a guess at the format:

```
users = 'Username:arozar
Index:654
AssignedIP:10.254.254.7
PublicIP:4.2.2.2
Protocol:AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel
License:AnyConnectEssentials
Encryption:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256
Hashing:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1
BytesTx:6104355
BytesRx:1191505
GroupPolicy:vpn
TunnelGroup:anyconnect
LoginTime:08:51:55ESTMonNov32014
Duration:1h:08m:48s
Inactivity:0h:00m:00s
NACResult:Unknown

VLANMapping:N/A
VLAN:none
Username:popeye
Index:655
AssignedIP:10.254.254.8
PublicIP:4.2.2.3
Protocol:AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel
License:AnyConnectEssentials
Encryption:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256
Hashing:AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1
BytesTx:6104355
BytesRx:1191505
GroupPolicy:vpn
TunnelGroup:anyconnect
LoginTime:09:52:56estmonnov32014
Duration:1h:08m:47s
Inactivity:0h:00m:00s
NACResult:Unknown

VLANMapping:N/A
VLAN:none
'
```

Here's code to break that into an array of hashes:

```
user_hashes = []
users.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).slice_before(/^Username/).each do |user|
  user_hashes << user.map{ |l| l.split(':', 2) }.to_h
end
```

And what `user_hashes` looks like:

```
user_hashes 
# => [{"Username"=>"arozar",
#      "Index"=>"654",
#      "AssignedIP"=>"10.254.254.7",
#      "PublicIP"=>"4.2.2.2",
#      "Protocol"=>"AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel",
#      "License"=>"AnyConnectEssentials",
#      "Encryption"=>
#       "AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256",
#      "Hashing"=>
#       "AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1",
#      "BytesTx"=>"6104355",
#      "BytesRx"=>"1191505",
#      "GroupPolicy"=>"vpn",
#      "TunnelGroup"=>"anyconnect",
#      "LoginTime"=>"08:51:55ESTMonNov32014",
#      "Duration"=>"1h:08m:48s",
#      "Inactivity"=>"0h:00m:00s",
#      "NACResult"=>"Unknown",
#      "VLANMapping"=>"N/A",
#      "VLAN"=>"none"},
#     {"Username"=>"popeye",
#      "Index"=>"655",
#      "AssignedIP"=>"10.254.254.8",
#      "PublicIP"=>"4.2.2.3",
#      "Protocol"=>"AnyConnect-ParentSSL-TunnelDTLS-Tunnel",
#      "License"=>"AnyConnectEssentials",
#      "Encryption"=>
#       "AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)AES256DTLS-Tunnel:(1)AES256",
#      "Hashing"=>
#       "AnyConnect-Parent:(1)noneSSL-Tunnel:(1)SHA1DTLS-Tunnel:(1)SHA1",
#      "BytesTx"=>"6104355",
#      "BytesRx"=>"1191505",
#      "GroupPolicy"=>"vpn",
#      "TunnelGroup"=>"anyconnect",
#      "LoginTime"=>"09:52:56estmonnov32014",
#      "Duration"=>"1h:08m:47s",
#      "Inactivity"=>"0h:00m:00s",
#      "NACResult"=>"Unknown",
#      "VLANMapping"=>"N/A",
#      "VLAN"=>"none"}]
```

[`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) is a great method that takes a pattern used to mark lines that should start a new sub-array.

Also, meditate on this as an alternative for your first three lines in your sample code:

```
ac_array = []
`show vpn-sessiondb anyconnect`.split("\n").reject(&:empty?).map{ |l| l.split(':', 2) }.to_h
```

That would only work for output like you displayed above for a single user.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following for each user.

**Code**

```
ATTRIBUTES = [:Username, :AssignedIP, :PublicIP, :License,
              :BytesTx, :BytesRx, :GroupPolicy, :TunnelGroup]

def hashify(text)
  text.each_line.with_object({}) do |line, h|
    ATTRIBUTES.each do |sym|
      v = line[/(?<=#{sym.to_s}:)\w+\S+/]
      h[sym] = v if v
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
text =
"Username:arozar
AssignedIP:10.254.254.7
PublicIP:4.2.2.2
License:AnyConnectEssentials
BytesTx:6104355
BytesRx:1191505
GroupPolicy:vpn
TunnelGroup:anyconnect"

hashify(text)
  #=> {:Username=>"arozar", :AssignedIP=>"10.254.254.7", :PublicIP=>"4.2.2.2",
  #    :License=>"AnyConnectEssentials", :BytesTx=>"6104355",
  #    :BytesRx=>"1191505", :GroupPolicy=>"vpn", :TunnelGroup=>"anyconnect"}
```

**Notes**

- If you really want an array of hashes, it's easy enough to convert the hash (`hashify(text).to_a.map {|k,v| {k=>v} }`), but consider whether you wouldn't be better off with a hash. That would give you an array of one hash per user. Better, I suspect, would be to have a single hash with one element for each user. For the user in the example, that key-value pair would be:

.

```
"arozar" => { :AssignedIP=>"10.254.254.7", :PublicIP=>"4.2.2.2",
              :License=>"AnyConnectEssentials", :BytesTx=>"6104355",
              :BytesRx=>"1191505", :GroupPolicy=>"vpn",
              :TunnelGroup=>"anyconnect" }
```

- If the hash values shown in the example are not what you want, you will need to modify `\w+\S+` [here the same as `(\w+\S+)`] in your regex.
- This uses the form of the method [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) that takes a regex as an argument.
- If you'd prefer, rather than using a regex, you could write `k,v = line.split(':'); u = v[/\w+\S+/]; h[sym] = u if u`, but I like it better as is.